# How to customize field size in TYPO3 BE

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using TYPO3 since version 3 but I have never tried to customize the TYPO3 BE.

Now, what annoys me more in the BE is that in 'Special Menus' the 'Selected Pages' field displays 3 lines by default.  I wish to expand it to at least 10 lines.

Inspecting the BE page with FF Developer Tools shows:

```
<select id="tceforms-multiselect-57f39f13067b0673730065" size="3" class="formField.
```

Editing the size value to 10 in the Inspector is exactly what I need.

How could I change that size value in TYPO3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Markusson and @Vimal Usadadiya

As suggested deactivating and activating the extension did the trick.  BTW no need to use Global. The code I put in ext_tables.php is:

```
$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['pages']['config']['size'] = 10;
```

Comment: $TCA is a global to and is deprecaded ;)

Comment: It appears in TCA Reference 6.2. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can override this in your own extension via

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['pages']['config']['size'] = 10;
```

Put it in `ext:your_ext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`
alternative in `ext:your_ext/ext_localconf.php`

[TYPO3 Reference to override TCA](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ExtendingTca/StoringChanges/Index.html#storing-in-the-overrides-folder)

Comment: I tried both places and neither one works.  As per the Reference since a1_teasermenu is an old extension my guess is that the procedure doesn't fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default value by using below lines. You can put that lines into ext_tables.php file in your custom extension.

```
unset($GLOBALS['TCA']['table_name']['columns']['field_name']['config']['size']);

$GLOBALS['TCA']['table_name']['columns']['field_name']['config']['size'] = 10;
```

Comment: It doesn't work.  Maybe the reason is that the extension I use a1_teasermenu is and old extension with fixed deprecated functions.

Comment: After put this code in ext_tables.php.
Please try with re-install both extension in sequence i.e. 1) a1_teasermenu and 2) your custom extension.